# Cant access all files and directories on my Raspberry Pi from Notepad++

Tags: raspberry-pi, notepad++

I can only see and access files saved in the home directory, and I need to edit files that are placed elsewhere on my Raspberry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit other files, just with `sudo` commands. If you want to edit a file like this, you need to use: `sudo nano <path to file>`